# Same section name in blade inherited templates

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Let's say i have three blade templates: A, B and C. Template A is the global layout, template B is some specific section's layout and template C is the view template.

Templates A and B expect a section called `content` to be assigned. That section is defined in the view templates (C).

Here's a simplified version of templates A and B:

Template A:

```
<html>
  <body>
    @yield('content')
  </body>
</html>
```

Template B:

```
@extends('template_a')

@section('content')
<div class="sidebar">
  ...
</div>
<div class="content">
  @yield('content')
</div>
@endsection('content')
```

As you can see, both templates output a `content` section. My problem is that in views that extend B it's content is simply ignored. The `content` section defined in the view is output on the `@yield('content')` present at template A.

I would like to know if it is possible to propagate the `content` section up in the view hierarchy, i.e., replacing the the content placeholder in template B with the value defined in template C and replace the result in `content` placeholder in template A.

Sorry if i made this sound too confusing. I hope you get my idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with @parent directive?

Comment: I've seen it and tried it but can't get it to do what i want. I think @parent is the opposite of what i want. I want to be able to put the childs content in the parent view and not the other way around.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found an answer to your problem here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/trouble-with-blade-section-inheritance?page=1

The trick is to use @overwrite instead of @endsection in the blades that contain a @yield inside a @section with the same name.

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
    {{--Some common code--}}
    @yield('content')
@overwrite
```

Using @endsection causes yielded views to override the intermediate view, but using @overwrite forces inclusion along the way.

The confusing thing, in my opinion, is that in conventional programming the directive to make use of the superclass method goes in the subclass (calling the superclass method from the subclass) whereas in Laravel blade inheritance it must be placed in the superclass itself (the superclass declares within itself that it cannot be ignored when overridden).

Comment: Not so confusing once we know that calling the superclass with `@parent` is possible, but using that we can only include the code of superclass (exactly like programming), and not what the OP needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the `@yield('content')` in Template B. *A `@endsection` (Laravel5) is enough to end those sections.*

Template A:

```
<html>
  <body>
    @yield('body')
  </body>
</html>
```

Template B:

```
@section('body')
   <div class="sidebar">
      ...
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      @yield('content')
   </div>
@endsection
```

Template C:

```
@section('content')
    <!--yourContent-->
@endsection
```

This way you can easily change your Template B with any other given Template to modify the body (i.e. Template D):

```
@section('body')
   <!-- Some different Body Style -->
      @yield('content')
@endsection
```

as well as your content (i.e. Template E):

```
@section('content')
    <!--some different Content-->
@endsection
```

**Edit:**

Probably the reason for Template B not showing any data from Template C is an infinite Loop caused by Template B: Every time you call the section('content') you also yield('content') and inserting Template B into itself.

Comment: I cant think of a good answer but I am opposed to your answer Tim. What if the OP wants to extend more than just template C from B, he will have to rename all of those as well. It works, but kind of sloppy and forces him to change all other views.

with that said, your post is a solution, but OP see if it fits you and if you dont mind this type of code

Comment: @alaboudi All in all I can't agree with you. The main reason for yields is to keep your code DRY. You can switch your body or content easily. But for that reason you need an unique identifier (the value of yield).
If you don't have an alternative Template for B I see no reason in using yields. Instead an include or using the same php file would work just fine. Edited my post for further examples.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My objective is to be able to extend either A or B without changing the main view. That's why they both have the section name `content`.